# Bash script won't release for Jenkins when calling subscript

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, jenkins

I have a script that calls a subscript and attempts to release/disown this script so that Jenkins calling the script can complete successfully.  It seems to release the script on the command line, so I can log out or execute other scripts when on the command line (SSH), but Jenkins hangs waiting for the released script to finish.  Is there a way around it?

## super.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/oracle/example/subscr.sh>temp-log.log</dev/null&
disown -h

echo "Done"
exit 0
```

## subscr.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ false ]; do
  echo "Still Working"
  sleep "5s"
done
```

When doing this, Jenkins just hangs endlessly until I kill the subscr execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `nohup /home/oracle/example/subscr.sh >temp-log.log &` instead of `disown -h` in super.sh.  In your version, stderr from subscr.sh is not redirected, and this may cause your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to be run in a wrapper from Jenkins, so this helped as we actually did this from the calling SSH script and it released.